# Is it possible to resize a view inside a fix size Box in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have a row that in the left side I can add a custom view, and in the right side I need a column with two text.

My problem comes in the left side. If I don't put a width in the left element (box) it occupies all the row and if I put a specific size of the element (box) this show the custom view looks flattened.

How can I add my customview align at the left part of the Row keeping the correct size of my custom view?

```
Row(
        Modifier
            .padding(top = 24.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(width= 115.dp, height= 40.dp)
            .align(Alignment.Bottom)){
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .wrapContentSize()){
                AndroidView(
                    factory = { context ->
                        MyView(context).apply {
                            seteViewListener(listener)
                        }
                    },
                )
            }
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Bottom)) {
            Text("Total",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                lineHeight = 16.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.app_grey_dark))

            Text(text = currentItem.totalPrice,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
                lineHeight = 24.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.app_black_dark))
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like it depends on how your custom view layout is made. With any compose view you don't need these two boxes one in an other, just pass modifier to the view and it would work fine

Comment: Yes, problem is that how view layout is done align me the icon at right. I think that for this I need to provide a box with a specifi size to remain in this position and no go to the right. Is possible?

Comment: I haven't worked much with android views, so it's hard to say without a reproducible sample. try `.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)`